# Explicitly invoking `int` destructor - why is a type alias required?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, c++17, primitive-types

The following program...

```
int main()
{
    int{1}.~int();
}
```

does not compile on *(see [conformance viewer](https://godbolt.org/g/HCsgAA))*:

- clang++ trunk, with `-std=c++1z`
- g++ trunk, with `-std=c++1z`
- CL 19 2017

---

Introducing a *type alias* for `int`...

```
int main()
{
    using X = int;
    int{1}.~X();
}
```

...makes the program valid on all previously mentioned compilers, without warnings *(see [conformance viewer](https://godbolt.org/g/Ktnhmt))*.

**Why is a type alias required when invoking `int`'s destructor?** Is this because `int` is not a valid grammar element for a destruction invocation?

Comment: Why would you ever want to invoke an int destructor?

Comment: Int is a native type, do you need a destructor for it?

Comment: @manni66: it makes sense in generic contexts *(e.g. implementing `std::optional`)*, but this question was created purely out of curiosity.

Comment: Looks like someone has been watching [C++ WAT](https://youtu.be/rNNnPrMHsAA?t=4m).

Comment: @nwp: oh wow, I actually attended that talk back in 2015. It was a ton of fun. This question has nothing to do with it, it originated from some discussion on my internal corporate C++ chat :)

Comment: It looks like it should work (see [bullet 7 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators))...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `t.~T()` works in a template, taking care of generic contexts. Can't say I can think of a situation where I'd want to use `int` directly.

Comment: Why the downvote? @chris: me neither, this is mostly a "language-lawyer" curiosity question.

Comment: I marked as duplicate because Columbo nailed it in his answer. "You can't actually call a destructor for scalars, because they don't have one (see §12.4). The statement is solely allowed for template code in which you call the destructor of an object whose type you don't know - it removes the necessity of writing a specialization for scalar types." -- I should note that 12.4 should be replaced with [class.dtor] for accuracy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works because the grammar didn't make provisions for built-in types, but it did make provisions for aliases:

[[expr.post]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.post#1):

> ```
> postfix-expression:
>     postfix-expression . pseudo-destructor-name
>     postfix-expression -> pseudo-destructor-name
>
> pseudo-destructor-name:
>     ~ type-name
>     ~ decltype-specifier
> ```

And [[dcl.type.simple]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#1):

> ```
> type-name:
>   class-name
>   enum-name
>   typedef-name
>   simple-template-id
> ```

You can imagine what each variable under `type-name` stands for. For the case at hand [[expr.pseudo]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.pseudo#1) specifies that it is just a `void` expression:

> The use of a pseudo-destructor-name after a dot . or arrow -> operator
>   represents the destructor for **the non-class type denoted by type-name
>   or decltype-specifier. The result shall only be used as the operand
>   for the function call operator (), and the result of such a call has
>   type void. The only effect is the evaluation of the postfix-expression
>   before the dot or arrow.**

The interesting thing to note, is that you should be able do that without an alias (if you have a named object), because the pseudo destructor call also works with a `decltype` specifier:

```
auto a = int{1};
a.~decltype(a)();
```

Comment: The last snippet doesn't compile for gcc (_"expected identifier before 'decltype'"_), but does for clang. Based on you rationale, is this a bug/limitation in gcc trunk? Related: for the specific case of this example (`int`), we can use the (apparent) fact that the `decltype` specifier applied to an integer literal yields type `int`, to construct `int{1}.~decltype(0)();` which compiles with clang. Moreover, peculiarly, `int{1}.~decltype(auto)();` crashes clang prompting us to file a bug report. For e.g. a custom POD `Foo`, `Foo{1}.~decltype(auto)();` does not crash, but yields an error.

Comment: @dfri - The dry letter of the standard indicates that as a bug in GCC, yes. And it should be fixed since the construct is legal. As for the crash in Clang... this is so much of an edge case I'm not sure it's worth the bug report.

Comment: Thanks. As for the clang crash, I agree, and would feel silly if posting a bug report for it.